# Why does deploying webapp to WebSphere with "Run server with resources within workspace" throw exception?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, rad

I have a web project with dependencies on other projects. When I deploy my project using 'Run server with server resources, it works'. When I switch to 'Run server with resources within workspace', it deploys and when my start up routine executes, it throws a ClassNotFoundException:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.somepackage.SomeClass

The class it complains about can be found in the project on which my web project depends on (a simple java project). That project has been added to the web project's class path as a full eclipse project (not just a jar) and also in the web project's deployment assembly.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What's the version of WebSphere AS? What's the tooling? Eclipse or RAD? What's the version?

Comment: What does the full stack trace look like? Given that this works in one mode but not the other, this is likely a defect in some product, and you should probably open a PMR with IBM.